# Erro ao buscar uma lista no banco

Tags: java, oracle

Eae pessoal,

Então estou com uma duvida no meu trabalho da faculdade,

tenho duas tabelas uma USUARIO e USUARIO_AMIGO ambas relacionadas, pelo java estou buscando uma lista de usuário que trás todos os usuários cadastrados, e uma outra lista que trás um amigo de um determinado usuário, so que não consigo trazer esses valores.

Meu codigo ListaTodos e ListaAmigos

```
public List<Usuario> buscarAmigos(int cdUsuario){
        String sql = "SELECT USUARIO_CD_USUARIO FROM USUARIO_AMIGO "
                + "INNER JOIN USUARIO "
                + "ON USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = USUARIO.CD_USUARIO "
                + "AND USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = ?";
        List<Usuario> amigos = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setInt(1, cdUsuario);
            ResultSet resultado = st.executeQuery();
            while(resultado.next()){
                Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setCdUsuario(resultado.getInt("CD_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setDataNasc(resultado.getString("DT_NASCIMENTO"));
                usuario.setFoto(resultado.getString("FOTO_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setLocalizacao(resultado.getString("NM_LOCALIZAO"));
                usuario.setNome(resultado.getString("NM_NOME"));
                usuario.setSobrenome(resultado.getString("NM_SOBRENOME"));
                usuario.setEmail(resultado.getString("EMAIL_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setNmUsuario(resultado.getString("NM_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setSexo(resultado.getString("TP_SEXO").charAt(0));
                amigos.add(usuario);
            }
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return amigos;
    }

    public List<Usuario> buscarTodos(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO";
        List<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);      
            ResultSet resultado = st.executeQuery();
            while(resultado.next()){
                Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setCdUsuario(resultado.getInt("CD_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setDataNasc(resultado.getString("DT_NASCIMENTO"));
                usuario.setFoto(resultado.getString("FOTO_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setLocalizacao(resultado.getString("NM_LOCALIZACAO"));
                usuario.setNome(resultado.getString("NM_NOME"));
                usuario.setSobrenome(resultado.getString("NM_SOBRENOME"));
                usuario.setEmail(resultado.getString("EMAIL_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setNmUsuario(resultado.getString("NM_USUARIO"));
                usuario.setSexo(resultado.getString("TP_SEXO").charAt(0));
                //usuario.setAmigos(this.buscarAmigos(usuario.getCdUsuario()));
                usuario.setAmigos(this.buscarAmigos(resultado.getInt("CD_USUARIO")));
                lista.add(usuario);
            }
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Classe de teste

```
// GET AMIGOS
        try {
            UsuarioDao dao = new UsuarioDao();
            List<Usuario> listaAmigos = dao.buscarAmigos(1);
            System.out.println("Amigos do usuario:");
            for (Usuario u : listaAmigos){
                System.out.println(u.getCdUsuario() + " - " + u.getNome() + " " + u.getSobrenome());;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        // GET USUARIOS
        try {
            UsuarioDao dao = new UsuarioDao();
            List<Usuario> listaUsuario = dao.buscarTodos();
            System.out.println("Lista de usuario:");
            for (Usuario u : listaUsuario){
                System.out.println(u.getCdUsuario() + " - " + u.getNome() + " " + u.getSobrenome());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

O erro que me retorna

```
java.sql.SQLException: Nome de coluna inválido
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3724)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getInt(OracleResultSet.java:438)
    at br.com.younews.dao.UsuarioDao.buscarAmigos(UsuarioDao.java:94)
    at br.com.younews.dao.UsuarioDao.buscarTodos(UsuarioDao.java:131)
    at br.com.younews.teste.TesteUsuarioDao.main(TesteUsuarioDao.java:67)
```

Minha tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: verifiquei todas

Comment: linha 67 - List<Usuario> listaUsuario = dao.buscarTodos();

Comment: Guilherme, edita a pergunta e coloca mais informações sobre as tabelas que você está utilizando pra ficar mais fácil identificar o problema. Um detalhe que achei estranho é que você começou falando que tem uma tabela `AMIGO_USUARIO` e no seu SQL você utiliza `USUARIO_AMIGO`.

Comment: tinha me confundido, corrigido

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, vejamos melhor a sua situação.

Na sua SQL, temos o seguinte:

```
 String sql = "SELECT USUARIO_CD_USUARIO FROM USUARIO_AMIGO "
            + "INNER JOIN USUARIO "
            + "ON USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = USUARIO.CD_USUARIO "
            + "AND USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = ?";
```

Ok, sendo assim, se você executar isso no IBExpert ou sql management studio ou qualquer outra coisa que execute SQL, você terá apenas a sua tupla(linha de resultado) com uma coluna.

```
USUARIO_CD_USUARIO
==================
1
2
3
```

Porém, no seu `ResultSet` você esta buscando por colunas que neste momento não existem na sua Query.

Experimente ao menos, declarar estar colunas na sua SQL.
Algo simples, como:

```
String sql = " SELECT USUARIO_AMIGO.* " 
           + " FROM USUARIO_AMIGO "
           + " INNER JOIN USUARIO ON (USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = USUARIO.CD_USUARIO) "
           + " WHERE USUARIO_AMIGO.USUARIO_CD_USUARIO = ?"
```

Ou melhor ainda, certifique-se em qual tabela estão os campos que você está tentando utilizar no `ResultSet` e escreva-os por extenso na sua SQL.

Utilize de preferência sempre `TABELA.CAMPO` pois isso facilita tanto para você entender o que está buscando da sua base de dados, quanto outra possa que possa vir a dar manutenção no código que você concebeu.

Mas pelo menos tente. Sim, os dados que você quer devem estar todos declarados na sua select, indiferente de como você utilizar `( "SELECT * FROM TABELA" ou "SELECT TABELA.CAMPO FROM TABELA ...")`

Comment: Agora faz sentido. Só falta excluir a outra resposta. Leia o [tour] para entender melhor o site. Aliás, bem vindo ao [pt.so]